# converter 1 em ativo e 0 inativo dentro de ng-repeat angular

Tags: angularjs, ng-repeat

Tenho um valor de flagAtivo que é 1 para ativo e 0 para inativo dentro de um `ng-repeat` que exibo em uma tabela, porém preciso que esse valor seja Ativo se 1 e inativo se 0

```
           <tbody ng-repeat="oper in operadorasCartoes" >
                <tr>
                  <td>{{oper.nome}}</td>                   
                   <td>{{oper.cnpj}}</td>
                   <td>{{oper.flagAtivo}}</td>                    
                </tr>               
              </tbody>
```

Tem como fazer pelo html ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma opção é utilizar um operador ternário:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="oper in operadorasCartoes" >
  <tr>
    <td>{{oper.nome}}</td>
    <td>{{oper.cnpj}}</td>
    <td>{{oper.flagAtivo === 1 ? 'Ativo' : 'Inativo'}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```